# Jscolors change color value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jscolor

I have jscolors input on page:

```
<input type="button" onchange="updateColor(this.jscolor)"
                   class="jscolor" value="d3d3d3"
                   style="border:none;border-radius:50%; width: 25px; height: 25px;">
```

How can i change its color in js? 
I tried it:

```
 $(this).parents('.leadsComboboxBlock').find('.jscolor').jscolor.fromString('ff9900');
```

But i get error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromString' of undefined"

How can i correct change jscolor for selector `$(this).parents('.leadsComboboxBlock').find('.jscolor')`

Comment: What is the context of your javascript code?  What is the `this` element in your case?

Comment: probably you selector is not correct `console.log($(this).parents('.leadsComboboxBlock').find('.jscolor'));` what do you see

Comment: I see [object Object]

Comment: $(this) - is a img element, i find its parents element and then .jscolor element

Comment: Anybody can help me?